# Bundler puts my gems in my project directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a Rails 3rc app on Ruby 1.9.2 that works fine, but Bundler keeps making a folder named "bandsintown" (bandsintown is a gem I use) in my project directory. From what I can tell, the folder has all my gems in it. I'm pretty sure that this never happened before. Is it normal behavior?

I think this might be interfering with running tests. I get a "Command failed with status (1)" error and then it mentions the "bandsintown" folder a few times.

I find it odd that Bundler names the folder "bandsintown" even when I comment out that gem in the gemfile. There's a "ruby" folder in that one, and a "1.9.1" folder inside the "ruby" folder. I don't understand why it says 1.9.1 when I'm using 1.9.2. The 1.9.1 folder has a bin, bundler, cache, doc, gems and specification folder inside of it.

I made a testapp with all the same gems and did a bundle install. It doesn't make a new folder with all my gems in it.

Anyway, my app works fine, but I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me out here. If I left out any need-to-know information, let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You are probably running the following command: `bundle install bandsintown`. That command tells bundler to install gems into the `bandsintown` subdirectory of your application. In order to install gems, all you need to do is modify your Gemfile and run `bundle install`.

Bundler will remember the location that you last specified in the .bundle/config file. So, in order to "reset" bundler's memory. In your application's directory, run `rm -r .bundle/config`.

Then, after updating your Gemfile, simply run `bundle install`

Comment: You can also run bundle install --system to reset the location to the default