# Why are gems installed in my project directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I have rvm installed and have created `.ruby-version` specifying `1.9.3` and `.ruby-gemset` specifying `my_project` in my project directory. And when i run `gem env gemdir` it returns: `/Users/danielfriisjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@my_project`.

However, when I run `bundle install`, all the gems that I have specified in my gemfile are put in `my_project/vendor/bundle/gems`

Comment: Try to run `bundle install --system`. Maybe this is a good answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408653/bundler-puts-my-gems-in-my-project-directory

Comment: Check location of bundle - `which bundle`. If it is not in .rvm or system gem space remove and re-install again.

Comment: `bundle install --system` just puts the gems in my local project directory as before. `which bundle` returns `/Users/danielfriisjensen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin/bundle`

Comment: Maybe you installed the bundle the first time in your project into /my_project/vendor? Bundler will remember the location that you last specified in the .bundle/config file. So, in order to "reset" bundler's memory. In your application's directory, run rm -r .bundle/config.

Comment: I'm very new to rails, so I might have done something like that. However, running `rm -r .bundle/config` returns `No such file or directory`

Comment: @Mattherick I had to run the command from root, and now everything works - Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundler was remembering the location from the first time I ran bundle install. Had to 'reset' bundler's memory be running `rm -r .bundle/config`