# bundle install creating a 'parallel' folder in the rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm currently working on a project which was changed from ruby version `2.0.0` to ruby verion `2.1.1`,

i'm using `rvm` for maintaining my ruby versions. After installing ruby `2.1.1`, I ran `gem install bundler` which installed version `1.6.2`, doing so I had copied  a specific gemset version to a newly created one for version `2.1.1` after which when running `gem list` on, it displayed all the gems, and when I tried to run the app it started throwing errors.

So when I ran `bundle install` again it created a separate folder **parallel** and installed the gems there. My question is why does this happen, is it a new feature of bundler `1.6.2`'?

Initially I had my bundler version to `1.5.2`.

Any input on this will be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Found this post which explains clearly, the reason was my config file was corrupted.

we have to remove .bundle/config file and bundle install again.

```
rm -r .bundle/config 
   bundle install
```

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408653/bundler-puts-my-gems-in-my-project-directory) for more information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have two different bundlers tied to a different RVM gemset, even if you tried to install the newest globally.

In the future you may consider using :

```
bundle install --path .bundle
```

to install your gems in a consistent manner, always in the same .bundle folder, no matter what RVM gemset you're using.